# In Elixir umbrella app, where should logger backend app be added as a dependency?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an Elixir umbrella application. The applications under the umbrella use [Logger](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/1.0.5/Logger.html). I want to add a backend ([logger_logstash_backend](https://github.com/marcelog/logger_logstash_backend)) for `:logger` application. So, I need to add that as a dependency in `deps` function in mix file.

In the outermost mix file of the umbrella application, the documentation of `deps` function states:

> Dependencies listed here are available only for this project
>    and cannot be accessed from applications inside the apps folder

That means I have to add the backend module as a dependency for each of the applications under the umbrella. However, doing so causes several problems:

1. It becomes harder to move out the individual applications as separate libraries later.
2. The individual applications under the umbrella are not actually dependent on the custom `:logger` backend module. They're okay with default `:console` backend. But I want to have an additional backend only for prod environment. Therefore, it's more of a cross-applications concern where I'm forced to add the dependency to each application individually.

Do you know any better strategy? What is it?

Answer (score 1):

Each application should have its own dependencies and configuration.

Problems that you mentioned:

> 1. It becomes harder to move out the individual applications as separate 
>      libraries later.

If you have configurations inside each app, this actually makes it easier to move out the individual applications out of the umbrella app. As mentioned in the [Elixir guides](http://elixir-lang.github.io/getting-started/mix-otp/dependencies-and-umbrella-apps.html#dont-drink-the-kool-aid), you simply need to move the app out of the `apps/` directory.

> 2. The individual applications under the umbrella are not actually dependent on the custom :logger backend module. They're okay with default :console backend. But I want to have an additional backend only for prod environment. Therefore, it's more of a cross-applications concern where I'm forced to add the dependency to each application individually.

If the custom logger backend is required only in production environment, then the apps can add this configuration only to `config/prod.exs` file and use this only in prod environment.

Comment: Logging is a cross-applications concern. If we make an application under umbrella depend on a particular backend of logger, how does it make easy to move the app out later? The app doesn't depend on logger to function.

Comment: In your example, the application does depend on the logger backend, but in production environment. It should be possible for you to move the application out of the umbrella app and still be able to run the app with `MIX_ENV=prod`. This is why keeping the dependencies and configurations inside each app makes it easier to move them out later.

Comment: It's possible that one or two apps under umbrella would be moved out and they won't need logger backend. In that case, keeping the dependency on logger backend inside each individual app makes it hard to move out.

Comment: Even if you move those apps out of the umbrella, you will still run them in prod environment and that will need this backend - so you need to keep the dependencies in individual apps. If you don't need that backend after moving out a particular app, just delete that dependency and update the config inside the app that now no longer needs this custom backend, that's all.

Comment: That's exactly why I was looking for a better way. It seems that, for now, there is no good way to deal with the cross-applications concerns in an application-independent way.

Comment: I know this is old, but maybe the (core) application you want to move out can be minimal just calling Logger.debug or so, and other applications depending on that core should also configure a whatever-custom-logger she needs, in her own config file. Shouldn't that log everything?

Answer (score 1):

Umbrella apps still have global configuration, IIRC. This means that if you do `config :logger, backends: [CustomBackend]` in one, you'll be configuring for them all.

With that in mind, recently I've been using two alternatives I'm happy with:

1. set the logger as a global dependency. I tend to use this when all the apps will always use the same backend and configuration. As an example, when I'm using the RingLogger backend and no other.
2. create a `logs` app. This may not be acceptable depending on how you are separating the apps. But I do this when I want more granular configuration (e.g. configuring an external logging service). Usually this has extra dependencies and configuration details that are abstracted within that app and don't leak to any other. If necessary, I have all other apps depend on it explicitly. It may seem too much of a hassle but I have some issues with configuring external services in the root app. I don't feel like service-specific dependencies should be a global dependency. Instead hiding them away and abstracting those within a logs app gives transparency and allows me to swap services if necessary.

I'm actually curious about the takes on this since I've been debating on it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the dependency in your outermost application(s). Then you can configure each of the applications to use the new logging backend.

Comment: "configure each of the applications to use the new logging backend" <-- it has the same 2 problems I have mentioned in the question.